# Is this the best method for updating Google Charts with AngularJS Directive?

Tags: angularjs, charts, angularjs-directive, bar-chart, pie-chart

I'm using a directive to generate various Google Charts for my project. The platform is new to me and I'd appreciate someone taking a look at this code and letting me know if this is the best approach for generating and updating charts.

As you can see, I have two $watch statements on bar and doughnut chart. At the moment, I have a button that calls the method to refresh the data...this will be automated in the future.

```
myApp.directive('gChart', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
        var myChartType = attrs.charttype || "bar"; 
            var chart = " ";    
                if( myChartType == "line" ) {
                    chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(elm[0]);
                }
                else if ( myChartType == "bar" ) {
                    scope.$watch('barData', function(){
                        console.log('barData changed');
                        chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(elm[0]);
                        chart.draw(scope.barData, scope.barOptions);
                    });
                }
                else if ( myChartType == "column" ) {
                    chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(elm[0]);
                }
                else if ( myChartType == "timeline" ) {
                    chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(elm[0]);
                    chart.draw(scope.timelineData, scope.timelineOptions);
                }
                else if ( myChartType == "donut" ) {
                    scope.$watch('donutData', function(){
                        console.log('donutData changed');
                        chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(elm[0]);
                        chart.draw(scope.donutData, scope.donutOptions);
                    });
                }       
        }
    }
});
```

HTML Usage:

```
<div g-chart chartType="bar"></div>
<div g-chart chartType="donut"></div>
<div g-chart chartType="timeline"></div>
```

It seems to be working well, but there are many things about AngularJS that I have yet to learn!